# Take $G$ a group such that ${\rm Hom}(G,\mathbb{R})=0$. Prove that $G$ is a finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

Take $G$ a group such that ${\rm Hom}(G,\mathbb{R})=0$. Now I have to prove that $G$ is a finite group.

But I don't know if it's true.

In fact I think that the "only" thing that I can say about $G$ is that every element of $G$ is of finite order but this doesn't imply that $G$ is finite. Any suggest or countrexample?

I was thinking about this and I think that maybe the right way is to prove that if $G$ is infinite so ${\rm Hom}(G, \mathbb{R})$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your doubts are justified, e.g. $G=\bigoplus_{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (or any other infinite torsion group) is a counter-example

Comment: The duplicate gives examples of such infinite groups, too.